# I want date and time picker with date also here is only time picker I want date also Here is the following code pls, help me in this

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I want date and time picker  with  date also here is only time picker I want date also... Here is the following code pls, help me in this. Here is H:i:s (hour: minutes:seconds)

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
         href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
          <input type="text"></input>
          <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
            format: 'hh:mm:ss',
            language: 'pt-BR',
             pickDate: false
          });
        </script>
      </body>
    <html>
```

Comment: What do you think `language: 'pt-BR'` does? What do you think `format: 'hh:mm:ss'` and `pickDate: false` do? You seem to have specified options that do the opposite of what you really want.

Answer (score 3):

I hope it should help you thanks.

```js
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
         
            language: 'en-US',
            format: 'dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss'
           
          });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
    <html>
      <head>
        <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen"
         href="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css">
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date">
          <input type="text"></input>
          <span class="add-on">
            <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
          </span>
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
        </script> 
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript"
         src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
        </script>
       
      </body>
    <html>
```